# Residual theorem for ellipse perimeter integral

Tags: complex-geometry, elliptic-curves, integration, quadratic-residues

Trying to use residual theorem for integrating ellipse perimeter.

- Can I use the residual theorem for the ellipse perimeter?
  [The calculation process I've followed so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pI5F0.jpg)
- If it cannot use the residual theorem, how to prove this inside function is not analytic in region $|z|\le 1$?
- If I can use the residual theorem, what is the order of pole for $z=0$?
- Is it possible to use the Laurent expansion to find the residual at $z=0$?
  I used the Laurent expansion but cannot get the correct answer.

Comment: Assuming your square root is the usual one with a cut on the negative real axis, what happens at $z=i\epsilon$ with sufficiently small (real) $\epsilon$?

Comment: Do you mean this contour integral cannot use the residual theorem? Is it not analytic in some part?Could you explicitly tell what would happen at z=iϵ  with sufficiently small (real) ϵ?

Comment: The square root cut on the negative axis by how, does this violate the condition to use the residual theorem?